# Grunt : Replace specific words in line

Tags: gruntjs, str-replace

Below is a class given from which i want to replace only specific lines.

```
class abc{

  Rest of code...

  Titan.include('`MyFunction/myControl`.js');

  Rest of code...

}
```

I want to replace `Titan.include` with `myfunc` and remove the word ".js" from the line:

```
myfunc('`MyFunction/myControl`');
```

I am using `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-string-replace');`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Okay, so what have you tried? Are getting any errors? We don't see what the problem is.

Comment: @jakerella i have tried below thing. But it could replace only first line of a file, other lines were same. dist: {
      files: [{
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'Resources/',
        src: '**/*.js',
        dest: 'Resources/'
      }],
      options: {
        replacements: [{
          pattern: 'Titan.include',
          replacement: 'myfunc'
        }]
      }
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use grunt-text-replace plugin you can configure it in the following way:

```
replace: {
      myReplace: {
        src: [ 'yourFile' ], //your file
        dest: 'destinationFile', //path and namefile where you will save the changes.
        replacements: [ {
          from: /Titan\.include\('(.*)\.js'\);/g,   //Regexp to match what you need
          to: "myfunc('$1');"   //Replacement for the Regexp
        } ]
      }
    }
```

Anyway, I never used the grunt-string-replace plugin, but if you NEED to use that instead grunt-text-replace I thing should work in this way:

```
'string-replace': {
  dist: {
    files: {
      'dest/': 'yourfile' //Key: path  where you will save the changes. Value: File or path where you will search.
    },
    options: {
      replacements: [{
        pattern: /Titan\.include\('(.*)\.js'\);/g,
        replacement: "myfunc('$1');"
      }]
    }
  }
```

Comment: files: [{
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'Resources/',
        src: '**/*.js',
        dest: 'Resources/'
      }] This parameters were missing in files